# AND Gate IC 7408, the number means?

Tags: integrated-circuit, logic-gates, code

Why it is 7408?

What does it mean?

Why it is used for AND Gate?

Comment: [AND Gate](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/and.html)

Comment: What? There is no explanation of this number.

Comment: Explanation for downvote?

Comment: Since the answer can be found [e.g. on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits) the questions seems to lack on research effort, which is a reason for downvotes.

Comment: Any answer can be found on the net if someone try hard to search it, or may be they found the answer but unknowingly overlooked it. But the answer, that maximum people find, is from Q&A site like "stackexchange". If everybody can find their answer in Wikipedia by through research and putting efforts then might be there was no "stackexchange" exist. I can show you thousand of questions in "stackexchange" that can be easily solved by searching the net, but still upvoted. And I guarantee that this question was never asked by anyone in the "stackexchange" sites before me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `74` says it is a commercial temperature range device. (read [Part numbering scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7400_series#Part_numbering_scheme) for details.)
- The `08` says it is a quad 2-input AND gate.

The 7400 series originated with TTL integrated circuits made by Texas Instruments. Because of the popularity of these parts, they were second-sourced by other manufacturers who kept the 7400 sequence number as an aid to identification of compatible parts (read more from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits)).

Comment: Thanks a lot!
"The 08 says it is a quad 2-input AND gate." - Why "08" was assumed?
And "74 commercial temperature range device", does it mean that the circuit can only be operated under 74 degree C?

Comment: http://www.interfacebus.com/Logic_Prefix_Temp_Range.html

Comment: The '08' part is just  a serial number - it has no more inherent meaning than a phone number, beyond letting you look it up in a catalogue : http://www.amazon.co.uk/TTL-Data-Book-Design-Engineers/dp/090404727X

Answer (score 3):

Texas Instruments, who originated this series of TTL logic circuits chose the first two digits as "74" to identify the series, possibly because that range of numbers didn't conflict with any existing parts.  The last two or three digits seem to be assigned in roughly the order of increasing complexity of the parts - low numbers are simple gates, while higher two-digit numbers get into flip-flops and simple counters.  Three-digit numbers are used for more complex functions.

Other than that simple-to-complex sequence, there doesn't seem to be any particular meaning to the numbers for a given function.

The 74XX parts are commercial temperature range -operating temperature range is 0 - 70 degrees C.  The equivalent 54xx series are military temperature range -55 to +125 degrees C.

For some IC families the part number does contain some information on the part (eg: memory size), but generally you should consider the part number as a randomly-assigned number, having no particular meaning.

Comment: The part numbers are not coincidentally assigned in order of increasing complexity, but they are historically assigned in order of design of those chips (need a number? The next one to use is ...). Likely they didn't expect to have more than 100 74-series ICs when they named the first one 7400 (and not 74000) The '245 is thus an older design than the '373.

Comment: Not really true - initially the numbers were grouped. For example the 7474 dual D flip flop was introduced at about the same time as the 7400 and the last two digits being 74 has been retained for the 174, 374 and 574 (hex and octal parts).  The parts such as 245, 373, 374 etc were introduced about the same time.  Similarly the 74573 is 74373 with a more convenient pinout.

Comment: @KevinWhite: it is true that we can see some patterns in the number assignments, but the answer to the OP's question "why does 7408 mean quad AND?" is still "7408 doesn't mean anything - it is just a part number."

Comment: Agreed - my comment was to Michael that the numbers were assigned in order of design.

Answer (score 0):

The TI 74xx series TTL logic family started out small, with very simple gates such as 2-input NANDs and inverters.

74, by the way, has nothing to do with degrees. As a matter of fact, the entire 74xx line was the commercial temperature range, 0 to 70 C. The military range (-55 C to 125 C, at somewhat relaxed specifications) was the 54xx line, with the last digits the same as for the 74xx line as far as logic function was concerned. And why these were chosen is known only to the TI marketing folk, who are mostly dead by now.

It seems clear that the line managers had a little thought for the future after the first 10 or 20 models were produced, but the first 10 to 20 are just a jumble of functions. The 740x chips were the very simplest - a 2-input NAND is a 7400, a 2-input OR is a 7402, a hex inverter is a 7404, and a 2-input AND is a 7408. Not widely remembered are intermediate numbers such as the 7401 and 7403(2-input NAND gate with open-collector outputs), 7406 and 7407 (hex inverting and non-inverting buffers with high-voltage outputs, and many others. Why these numbers were assigned in this particular order has been lost to history. Probably it just happened that the design teams declared them ready for release in that order.

It also seems clear that originally there was supposed to be a certain amount of function clustering by number. 7410 and 7411 are 3-input NAND and AND gates, 7420 and 7421 are 4-input NAND and AND gates, 7430 is an 8-input NAND gate and so on. Even so, the ordering really doesn't make much sense except if you think of it as the order in which new circuits were realized. The 7427, for instance is a 2-input OR gate, and why it is so far removed from the 7402 is anybody's guess.

The 747x range is almost entirely flip-flops, the most common being the 7474, but there are a bunch of others in this range.

The 745x and 746x is full of things like odd AND-OR combinations that never gained wide usage.

As TI gained experience they began shifting from SSI (small-scale integration, such as individual gates) to MSI (medium-scale integration) most notably with the 7490, the first decade counter. After that, the order of numbers seems to reflect a steady increase in circuit complexity and number of transistors, but that's really about all you can say.

About the time they hit the 742xx mark, microprocessors started getting popular, and various byte-oriented chips in bigger packages (20-pin) became the norm. The 74240 (inverting octal bus driver), 74244 (non-inverting octal bus driver), 74373 (octal latch) and 74374 (octal flip-flop) were probably the best-known, but there are various intermediate functions, such as octal flip-flops with master clear (74277) and octal flip-flop with clock enable (74377), plus others.